# if-statement body height < 100% javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

In my site I have not set a height for a html or a body tag. This works great on pages with lots of content, but when the content on a page is not enough to fill the page up, I want the body height to be 100%.

So I thought a bit of jQuery might help me out. I've come up with this little snippet which I thought would be adequate but unfortunately it doesn't do all too much.

```
if(jQuery("html").css("height") < "100%"){
    jQuery("html, body").css({"height": "100%", "min-height":"100%"});
}
```

I'm guessing that this may be because the jQuery may not picking up the body height as a percentage, maybe just in pixels.

Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: why not just set height to 100% for every page?

Comment: Replace jQuery with a $ you look to have picked the snippet out of a plugin

Comment: @KryptoniteDove why? `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`

Comment: @KryptoniteDove: that has nothing to do with anything and is actually perfectly okay. In some scenarios you actually have to use `jQuery` instead of `$`, such as when in no conflict mode.

Comment: Had to use jQuery instead of $ in no conflict mode for Drupal. And setting the height to 100% for every page does not work because when the content is longer than 100% it goes over the footer it it's absolutely positioned to the bottom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with **100% height layout.** Without any javascript.

Check this:

http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html (have used in my projects)

http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/index.php/100-height-layout-using-css/

Anyway, if you want to do this via jQuery:

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

You can define if `document` height less then `window` then set documents height to body or your main `<div id=container></div>` if you have such.

Answer (score 0):

Apply below css to your body/html

html, body { min-height:100%; height:auto }